# FiveM Server Error Linux ubuntu 18.04 Yarn

Tags: fivem

I am running a FiveM server inside the Pterodactyl Panel and when i updated recently to 3184 it started having this issue and i have no idea how to fix it i have tried reinstalling creating a fresh install downgrading and it keeps spitting out this error.

````
    compromised = compromised || function (err) { throw err; };
                                                  ^

Error: Unable to update lock within the stale threshold
    at /home/container/resources/[system]/[builders]/yarn/yarn_cli.js:89075:66
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:146:23) {
  code: 'ECOMPROMISED'
}
Building resource webpack failed.
Error data: yarn failed!```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with the new Pterodactyl Panel's FiveM egg. Currently, I am not sure if there is an official solution for this since I stopped using Pterodactyl Panel from a few months. But there is a workaround that I found when I was using it. Here's how it works.

**Step 1:**

Download the resource that is causing this issue on your computer.

**Step 2:**

Download and set up a default FiveM server on your computer, start the server and then start the resource.

**Step 3:**

Once you start the resource, it should install all the yarn dependencies needed and it'll restart the resource when it's done. You should see a message in the server console saying something like build complete.

**Step 4:**

Upload the resource folder to your server. Now when you start your server it should not give you any errors and the resource should be started successfully.

**What does this exactly do?**

Yarn needs to create directories and files etc when it needs to build a resource but Pterodactyl Panel does not give FiveM the permission to create these files due to whatever reason. So, outside of the Pterodactyl Panel there is no restriction and the files/directories are created without any issue therefore the build succeeds.